# Reversing a linked list effects the head pointer of the original list in main(). So not able to compare the reversed list and original list - C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am writing a program to check whether a singly linked list is a palindrome or not. For that, I want to reverse the list, and compare it to the original list.
But I am facing the following problem - when I reverse the list, the head pointer of the original list gets modified, and points to NULL.
So, when I have the following original list, following happens after reversing the original list:

1. Original list: 1->1->2->1->NULL
2. Reversed list: 1->2->1->1->NULL
3. But, after calling reverseList, the Original list becomes: 1->NULL

This is, because I have the following code to reverse the list:

```
 ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head)
 {
     ListNode* temp = head;
     ListNode* temp1 = temp;
     ListNode* current = NULL, * nextNode = NULL;
     if (temp)
         current = temp->next;
     if (current)
         nextNode = current->next;
     while (current)
     {
         current->next = temp;
         temp = current;
         current = nextNode;
         if (current)
             nextNode = current->next;
     }
     temp1->next = NULL;
     return temp;
 }
```

As soon as I do `temp1->next = NULL` in the above `reverseList` function (the second last line in the function), the head of the original list is modified and the original list now points to 1->NULL, instead of 1->1->2->1->NULL.

Below if the full code, that calls the function reverseList:

```
 struct ListNode
 {
     int val;
     ListNode* next;
     ListNode(int x):val(x),next(NULL){}
 };

 ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head)
 {
     ListNode* temp = head;
     ListNode* temp1 = temp;
     ListNode* current = NULL, * nextNode = NULL;
     if (temp)
         current = temp->next;
     if (current)
         nextNode = current->next;
     while (current)
     {
         current->next = temp;
         temp = current;
         current = nextNode;
         if (current)
             nextNode = current->next;
     }
     temp1->next = NULL;
     return temp;
 }

 bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
     //reverse the Linked list and then compare the two lists.
     if (head == NULL)
         return true;
     ListNode* head1 = head;
     ListNode* head2 = reverseList(head);
     while (head1 && head2)
     {
         if (head1->val != head2->val)
             return false;
         head1 = head1->next;
         head2 = head2->next;
     }
     return true;
 }

 int main()
 {
     ListNode* head = new ListNode(1);
     head->next = new ListNode(1);
     head->next->next = new ListNode(2);
     head->next->next->next = new ListNode(1);
     head->next->next->next->next = NULL;
     bool palindrome = isPalindrome(head);
     cout << palindrome << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

So, when the reverseList function returns, following happens in `isPalindrome` function:

1. `head2` is set to: `1->2->1->1->NULL`
2. `head` and `head1` are set to `1->NULL`

And I can no longer compare the two linked lists to check if they are palindromes of each other (since the comparison will give me wrong result).

This all is happening because I set `temp1->next=NULL` in the `reverseList` function.

Do you know how I should properly terminate the list in `reverseList` function, such that it does not effect the original list?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `reverseList` function modifies the existing list.  You'll want to make a deep copy of your list before reversing it (or while reversing it).

Comment: Hi @1201ProgramAlarm, I incorporated Deep Copy of the original list in my answer below, and I think the way I incorporated it is correct now? I am getting the right results now.
Please let me know, if the deep copy should be implemented somewhat differently?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Following is the corrected code, where I incorporated the Deep Copy of the original list (in `isPalindrome` function):

```
 struct ListNode
 {
     int val;
     ListNode* next;
     ListNode(int x):val(x),next(NULL){}
 };

 ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head)
 {
     ListNode* temp = head;
     ListNode* temp1 = temp;
     ListNode* current = NULL, * nextNode = NULL;
     if (temp)
         current = temp->next;
     if (current)
         nextNode = current->next;
     while (current)
     {
         current->next = temp;
         temp = current;
         current = nextNode;
         if (current)
             nextNode = current->next;
     }
     temp1->next = NULL;
     return temp;
 }

 bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
     //reverse the Linked list and then compare the two lists.
     if (head == NULL)
         return true;
     ListNode* head1 = head;
     ListNode* temp1 = NULL, *temp2=NULL;
     bool firstEntry = true;

     //Deep Copy
     temp2 = temp1 = new ListNode(head1->val);
     while (head1->next)
     {
         temp1->next = new ListNode(head1->next->val);
         temp1 = temp1->next;
         head1 = head1->next;
     }

     temp1->next = NULL;
     ListNode* head2 = reverseList(head);
     while (temp2 && head2)
     {
         if (temp2->val != head2->val)
             return false;
         temp2 = temp2->next;
         head2 = head2->next;
     }
     return true;
 }

 int main()
 {
     ListNode* head = new ListNode(1);
     head->next = new ListNode(1);
     head->next->next = new ListNode(2);
     head->next->next->next = new ListNode(1);
     head->next->next->next->next = NULL;
     bool palindrome = isPalindrome(head);
     cout << palindrome << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You're leaking all the memory you allocate, both in `isPalindrome` for the deep copy and in `main` for the original list.